# Is using identityHashCode to order synchronizing still valid in Java 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

To prevent deadlock on methods where they accept two parameters of the same type

```
method(Clazz class1, Clazz class2)
```

Which could be called by two threads with the same arguments in different order

```
method(a,b)
method(b,a)
```

And to prevent the issue caused by ordering locks on parameter order

```
 synchronized (class1) {
  synchronized (class2) { 
        }
    }
```

Is instead ordering locks using the identityHashCode result of the objects to lock on still a valid approach in Java 8?

This is described in the Concurrency In Practice book which is only Java 6.

Comment: Since Java has to be backwards compatible with existing code, why would this approach suddenly be *in*valid? Are you asking if there is a more up-to-date alternative?

Comment: identityHashCode has never been guaranteed to be unique, so I don't see how that ever could have been valid.

Comment: Double-checked locking was once always advised too

Comment: @user2357112 it is not guaranteed, but the chances of an object having the same hash code as another specific object are very low. (As in, even though you only need 77.4k objects before it is probable you have a collision, the chance of the two objects you are ordering having the same code is 1 in 4bn)

Comment: So your saying there's a chance? Maybe it would be better to assign a numerical value that you increment and set as a member variable to each Clazz in this example? Then order the locking off that?

Comment: @AndyTurner: 1 in 4 billion doesn't take as long to hit as it used to, and depending on implementation details, the collision chance can be higher than that - for example, if hash codes are based on address and objects get moved after their identityHashCode is taken, two objects initially allocated at the same address are likely to have equal hashes.

Comment: @user2357112 you can allocate 4bn objects, but that doesn't mean that the chances of two given objects having the same hash code is any different. It's like if you're in a room with 1 other person, the chance of them having the same birthday is 1/365; if there are 10 other people in the room and you pick one at random, the chance they have the same birthday is 1/365; if there are 1000 people in the room and you pick one at random, the chance they have the same birthday is still 1/365. Sure, there are reasons why the chance of collision is more likely, but it is still *pretty* unlikely.

Comment: @AndyTurner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem would disagree

Comment: @UserF40 like I said previously: if you have 77.4k objects, it is more likely than not that at least two of them have the same hash code, the result from the birthday paradox. But if you pick any two objects at random, the chance of them having the same hash code is 1 in 4bn (assuming uniform distribution of hash codes). You're not attempting to order all the possible objects, just the two you are currently dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

In a word - yes. The same principles still hold in Java 8.